# td content Javascript change color and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, nodes

So, I have a table with text. There are `<th>` and `<td>` in the table. On certain cells, depending upon the text of the cell, I want the background to change a certain color and on one particular cell if it contains a "+" sign, I want to change the color and delete the "+" sign.

This is what I have. It breaks when it gets to an empty cell and the "+" replace is too strict, i.e. it will remove the "+" only if that is the only thing in the cell. If it is "8+" it will not remove the "+" sign.

I'm new when it comes to Javascript. I'm sure this could be done a lot simpler.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>SAT</th>
    <th>SUN</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>8+</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el.html())
  }


var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
var node = allTableCells[i];

//get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

//check for certain content and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
if (!isEmpty($(currentText))) {
if (currentText === "K")
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
else if (currentText === "+")
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#0070c0";node.childNodes[0].nodeValue = currentText.replace("+", " ");
}
}

var allTableHeaders = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for(var ic = 0, max = allTableHeaders.length; ic < max; ic++) {
var node = allTableHeaders[ic];

//get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
var currentHeadText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

//check for certain days of the week and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
if (!isEmpty($(currentHeadText))) {
if (currentHeadText === "SAT")
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
else if (currentHeadText === "SUN")
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#91CF4F";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be checking if `currentText` contains a `+`, not checking if they are equal,

```
if (currentText.indexOf("+") > -1)
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#0070c0";
    node.childNodes[0].nodeValue = currentText.replace("+", " ");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do want that. Thank you, but my other issue is when the td doesn't have anything. In my example, I have a space, but if there is no space, it breaks it and stops checking the other td's.

Comment: When `node.childNodes[0].nodeValue` is null `<td></td` instead of `<td> </td>` it doesn't go any further.

Comment: Check if it's null, if it is, don't do anything

Comment: I can't figure out how to check if the node is empty :/

Comment: Ok, this jQuery does exactly what I want, but putting it in Wordpress doesn't work. So, can anyone help me convert this to Javascript?

`$("table.schedule th:contains('SAT')").css('background-color', '#ff0000');
$("table.schedule th:contains('SUN')").css('background-color', '#91CF4F');
$("table.schedule td:contains('K')").css('background-color', '#ffff00');
$("table.schedule td:contains('*')").css('background-color', '#0070c0');
$(document).ready(function() {
    var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/\*/g,'');
    $('body').html(strNewString);
});`

Comment: I figured it out. I put a function to check for `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` and then called `$j` for each instead of `$` My only issue was that `contains` was any and I needed it to be an exact match for certain ones, so I used `filter` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ammendments are needed...
the way you use isEmpty, you don't need to call .html() on it's argument. Also, as the previous answer suggested, test for the containment of "+" in currentText using jQuery indexOf().

```
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el)
}

var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var $currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for certain content and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
    if (!isEmpty($currentText)) {
        if ($currentText === "K")
            node.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
        else if ($currentText.indexOf("+") != -1){
            node.style.backgroundColor = "#0070c0";
            node.childNodes[0].nodeValue = $currentText.replace("+", " ");
        }
    }
}

var allTableHeaders = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for(var ic = 0, max = allTableHeaders.length; ic < max; ic++) {
    var node = allTableHeaders[ic];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var currentHeadText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for certain days of the week and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
    if (!isEmpty(currentHeadText)) {
        if (currentHeadText === "SAT")
            node.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        else if (currentHeadText === "SUN")
            node.style.backgroundColor = "#91CF4F";
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this in, but it stops after the K and doesn't color any of the cells and doesn't go past checking the other cells after K. The first check is on the td's, so it doesn't go any further after it encounters a null in the td after K.

Comment: So if you have '<td></td>' instead of '<td> </td>' it doesn't work.